# Uninstalling OpenSSL for older version

Tags: openssl

I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.0 and I'd like to roll back to the previous version.  I'd like to uninstall the version I have currently installed on my mac, but the instructions in the Make file are really ambiguous and Im a novice when it comes to this kind of stuff.  I posted the uninstall instructions below.  Am I looking at this wrong?  This doesn't look straightforward.

`uninstall_sw: uninstall_runtime uninstall_engines uninstall_dev`

```
uninstall_dev:
@echo "*** Uninstalling development files"
@ : 
@set -e; for i in $(SRCDIR)/include/openssl/*.h \
          $(BLDDIR)/include/openssl/*.h; do \
    fn=`basename $$i`; \
    echo "$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/include/openssl/$$fn"; \
    $(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/include/openssl/$$fn; \
done
-$(RMDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/include/openssl
-$(RMDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/include
@set -e; for l in $(INSTALL_LIBS); do \
    fn=`basename $$l`; \
    echo "$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/$$fn"; \
    $(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/$$fn; \
done
@ : 
@set -e; for s in $(INSTALL_SHLIB_INFO); do \
    s1=`echo "$$s" | cut -f1 -d";"`; \
    s2=`echo "$$s" | cut -f2 -d";"`; \
    fn1=`basename $$s1`; \
    fn2=`basename $$s2`; \
    : ; \
    echo "$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/$$fn1"; \
    $(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/$$fn1; \
    if [ "$$fn1" != "$$fn2" ]; then \
        echo "$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/$$fn2"; \
        $(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/$$fn2; \
    fi; \
    : ; \
done
@ : 
$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
-$(RMDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)/pkgconfig
-$(RMDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/$(LIBDIR)


uninstall_engines:
@echo "*** Uninstalling engines"
@set -e; for e in dummy $(INSTALL_ENGINES); do \
    if [ "$$e" = "dummy" ]; then continue; fi; \
    fn=`basename $$e`; \
    if [ "$$fn" = 'ossltest.dylib' ]; then \
        continue; \
    fi; \
    echo "$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(ENGINESDIR)/$$fn"; \
    $(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(ENGINESDIR)/$$fn; \
done
-$(RMDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(ENGINESDIR)

uninstall_runtime:
@echo "*** Uninstalling runtime files"
@set -e; for x in dummy $(INSTALL_PROGRAMS); \
do  \
    if [ "$$x" = "dummy" ]; then continue; fi; \
    fn=`basename $$x`; \
    echo "$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/bin/$$fn"; \
    $(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/bin/$$fn; \
done;
@set -e; for x in dummy $(BIN_SCRIPTS); \
do  \
    if [ "$$x" = "dummy" ]; then continue; fi; \
    fn=`basename $$x`; \
    echo "$(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/bin/$$fn"; \
    $(RM) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/bin/$$fn; \
done
@ : 
-$(RMDIR) $(DESTDIR)$(INSTALLTOP)/bin
```

Comment: "*I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.0 and I'd like to roll back to the previous version*" -- Why?

Comment: There's an issue getting postgres configured with OpenSSL.  https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160627151604.GD1051@msg.df7cb.de

Comment: @Brosef - Its not just Postgres; it includes other popular libraries, like Boost. Also see [Issue 12238: Boost fails to compile using OpenSSL 1.1.0](http://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12238).

Answer (score 0):

> Im a novice when it comes to this kind of stuff. I posted the uninstall instructions below. Am I looking at this wrong? This doesn't look straightforward....

There are three major components installed during `make install`:

- openssl program
- openssl headers and libraries
- man pages

During `make install_sw` there are two major components installed (I use this one because the man pages take too long to copy and take up too much space):

- openssl program
- openssl headers and libraries

Now, both of them depend on your earlier configuration with `--prefix` and  `--openssldir`. If you followed [Compilation and Installation](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) from the OpenSSL wiki, then you probably configured like:

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc shared enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 \
    no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl
```

Followed by a `make install` (software+man pages).

In this case, `cd` into `openssl-1.1.0` (where you built the library), and then do a `sudo make uninstall`. Follow that with a `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/ssl` and most cruft should be cleared. Any artifacts remaining will be overwritten by the OpenSSL 1.0.2 files.

If needed, `cd` into `openssl-1.1.0` and then reconfigure using the *exact* same configuration as used during the previous install. Then, perform the `make uninstall`.

---

OpenSSL 1.1.0 changed some Makefile behavior. If you *did not* use `make install_sw`, then it should not matter to you. Also see [OpenSSL Issue 4601: install_sw does not honor --openssldir](http://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-dev/2016-June/007772.html).

Comment: My only actions when installing OpenSSL were `./config`, `make`, `make test`, and `make install`.  `openssl-1.1.0` is the package i downloaded, that contains all the install files, Make file, etc., right?

Answer (score 0):

With below description my issue is resolved,

In this case, cd into openssl-1.1.0 (where you built the library), and then do a sudo make uninstall. Follow that with a sudo rm -rf /usr/local/ssl and most cruft should be cleared. Any artifacts remaining will be overwritten by the OpenSSL 1.0.2 files.